# Least cost path based on flow direction

Tags: qgis, cost-path, water

I need to find least cost path between two points inside a river polygon. The least cost path criteria is water flow direction, I need to follow the water flow to waste as little energy as possible.

I found out that flow direction maps exist in ArcGIS, and I've created something similar for QGIS.The blue lines are flow direction lines. And red line is a direction between start and end points.

Now I want to use Least cost path plugin to calculate the shortest path. But I don't know how to do it. Maybe someone has encountered such a problem or has any ideas? I'm new in QGIS and geographic and I looked for ways but found nothing at all.

[image]

Comment: Such path exists only if point downstream sits on a flow path from upper point.

Comment: But what's if it would be not ideal path? I think that the Fastest path (point to point) could be helpful if I could calculate speed and direction fields

Comment: Wouldn't you need a flow accumulation surface for this?  https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/r.flow.html

Comment: I don't understand what your image is showing. That's not what I'd think of when someone said a flow direction map

Comment: @Tom Brennan Is it possible to create a flow map in QGIS or is this only for ArcGIS? I don't have a map and I try to create something similar but I don't how to use it, how to extract information from it

Answer (score 2):

You may need to break your original question down into separate questions.

Below is is what I would call a flow direction map. It's based off a raster DEM and each pixel has a flow direction in one of the 8 primary directions, using values from 1-128 (2^x). The raster is the actual flow direction map, the arrows are just for visualisation purposes.

This one was generated using Whitebox Tools **D8Pointer** algorithm. There are also SAGA tools that will produce flow direction eg **Catchment Area** has a Channel Direction option.

[image]

A flow direction map like this can be used as part of a least cost path analysis. It may be worth reading the information on the CostDistance and CostPathway tools in Whitebox Tools: https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/gis_analysis_distance_tools.html#costdistance

They may be helpful in establishing what input data you need.